# Determinant of this skew symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, skew-symmetric-matrices

> How to prove the  determinant of
>
> $$A=(a_{ij})_{n\times n}=b_i^2-b_j^2$$ where $b_1,b_2,...,b_n$ are some distinct real numbers , $n\geq 3$  and  $i,j=1,2,...,n$  is zero?

Here,  $A$ is skew symmetric and I know odd order skew symmetric matrix has determinant zero. How about the even case? or Is there any other method to show $\det(A)=0$ ?

Comment: It is zero when $n \geq 3$. Indeed, this is a particular case of the fact that $\det\left(\left(x_i+y_j\right)_{1\leq i\leq n,\ 1\leq j\leq n}\right) = 0$ whenever $n \geq 3$. For this fact, see, e.g., Example 5.28 in [*Notes on the combinatorial fundamentals of algebra*, 7 November 2017](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/primes2015/sols.pdf).

Comment: The comment by @darijgrinberg gives a very nice explanation, and it is impressive to see this writing which is nearly 800 pages long! (I wish that I could study this some day!) Nevertheless a very quick explanation is possible, you do not quite have to find an example in the middle of $>780$ pages. The matrix $(b_i^2)$ has rank $1$ because each row is constant. The matrix $(b_j^2)$ has rank $1$ because each column is constant. The difference is a matrix of rank $2$ at most. If $n \geq 3$, an $n \times n$ matrix of rank $2$ or less has determinant zero.

Comment: @ZachTeitler: Thanks, but there's probably little new in there for you :) I was focussing on writing up in full detail the standard arguments that often end up in the no-mans-land between linear algebra and combinatorics.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Well, most of the main topics are familiar, but I'm sure that I could learn a lot from the examples. Hopefully some day. (Or perhaps I will convince a student to read it and tell me about it. :-) )

Answer (score 3):

From the comments: $A$ is the difference of two rank-one matrices, so that the rank of $A$ is at most two. It follows that $\det A = 0$ if $n \ge 3$.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it, at least not for all $n$, as the question was originally asked.

Pick $b_1 = 1$ and $b_2 = 0$ to get the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0}
$$
whose determinant is *not* zero.

Comment: Fine! Actually we consider the case $n \geq3$ (I have edited the question.)

Comment: Actually, you *asked* about the *general* case. Changing the question after folks have answered what you asked originally is a bit rude. Better, in the future, to make sure you're asking the question you wanted to ask right from the start.